# What is the origin of the term "involution" used in Hamiltonian mechanics

Tags: physics, terminology, classical-mechanics

We say that two dynamical variables $f$ and $g$ are in involution if their Poisson bracket vanishes, i.e., $\{f,g\}=0$. Why is it called involution?

Answer (score 2):

An involution is, according to the [*OED*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/99200#eid16688), "A function or transformation that is equal to its inverse."

Whittaker discusses involution systems in his [*A Treatise on the Analytic Dynamics of Particles and Rigid Bodies*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4482) p. 322:

> **147**. *Invoultion systems.*
>
> Let $(u_1,, u_2 , …, u_r)$ denote $r$ functions of $n$ independent variables $$(q_1, q_2 , …, q_n , p_1, …, p_n);$$if it is possible to express all the Poisson-brackets $(u_i,u_k)$ as functions of $(u_1,u_2,…,u_r)$, the functions $(u_1,u_2,…,u_r)$ are said to form a *function-group**. Any function of $(u_1,u_2,…,u_r)$ belongs to this group.
>
> If the quantities $(u_i,u_k)$ are all zero, the functions $(u_1,u_2,…,u_r)$ are said to be *in involution*, or to form an *involution-system*.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>*Lie, *Math. Ann.* VIII. (1875). p. 215.</sup>